# What's the meaning of "What am I missing here?"?

Tags: meaning

> I make to close my room door, but Kofi blocks it with his hand. “Big
> Madam wants you,” he says. [...] Why would she ask you to come to her
> room? She never asks anyone into her room —least of all you. What am I
> missing here?”

Could you please tell me what the meaning of "What am I
missing here?" is?

The fuller text is here:

> Kofi shakes his head. “Abu might have something; she always gave him
> the shopping list. I would ask him, but he’s been away as well since
> last night. He should be back this morning.” I make to close my room
> door, but Kofi blocks it with his hand. “Big Madam wants you,” he
> says. “She said you should come straight up to her room, right inside.
> Why would she ask you to come to her room? She never asks anyone into
> her room—least of all you. **What am I missing here?**” “Thank you,” I
> say, and close the door.

From: *[The Girl with Louding Voice](https://www.reads2020.com/romance/1708/1708_75.html)* by Abi Dare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means

> What are you not telling me here? What is the secret? What are you hiding? Fill me in on this!

Kofi suspects that there might be some communication between Big Madam and the person who writes in the 1st person, or some aspect of their relationship that he is not aware of. He might be ***concerned or worried*** either for himself or for Big Madam.

In other contexts such a sentence may even express the ***feeling of being threatened*** by one's ignorance of the facts suspected.